# Register all viewmodel and services in ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am developing a new MVVM light Wpf application.I have 25 View and  ViewModels and 25 DataService Interface and its implementations (One implementation for Design time Data service and one for realtime dataservice).

For Eg, Here is a my DataService Interface for my SupplierViewModel:

```
interface ISupplierDataService
{
    ObservableCollection<Tbl_Supplier> GetAllSuppliers();
    int GetSupplierCount(string supplierNameMatch);
}
```

and Here is its implementation for design time :

```
class SupplierDataServiceMock : ISupplierDataService
{

    public ObservableCollection<Tbl_Supplier> GetAllSuppliers()
    {
      .....
    }

    public int GetSupplierCount(string supplierNameMatch)
    {
      ....
    }
}

class SupplierDataService : ISupplierDataService
{

    public ObservableCollection<Tbl_Supplier> GetAllSuppliers()
    {
      ....
    }

    public int GetSupplierCount(string supplierNameMatch)
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

In ViewModelLocator is I need to register all my 25 ViewModels and its 25 DataService and its implementations like this :

```
 static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISupplierDataService, SupplierDataServiceMock>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICustomerDataService, CustomerDataServiceMock>();
            ....
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISupplierDataService, SupplierDataService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICustomerDataService, CustomerDataService>();
            ....
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SupplierViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CustomerViewModel>();
        ....
    }
```

My question is do I need to register all my 25 ViewModels and its 25 DataService in my ViewModelLocator ?

Comment: @Mashton ,I added my question

Comment: Yes you have to add all viewmodels and services in locator.

Comment: @DhavalPatel ,ok so what are the benefits I get when doing so

Comment: you don't need to register again in your application

Comment: Does memory consumption bother you? No one instances are created until viewmodel or service are resolved..

Comment: @SergePashkevich ,suppose I have 100 above viewModels and its corresponding Services ,create and cache all its instances will cause Performance degrades right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility would be to write a factory class `ViewModelResolver` this can then be injected by `SimpleIoc` (given you have an `IViewModelResolver`).

The main purpuse is to deliver a ViewModel. You can do it based on conventions, by string, by type, whatever fits best for you.

So for example `ViewModelResolver.GetViewModelFor("Namespace.CustomerView");`

This could be done per convention and reflection for example to return a new Instance of `CustomViewModel`...
With this you do also have control whether you like to retrieve a cached view model (always the same) or generate a new on each request...

This is just example to get you the idea... The implementation depends on your requirements...

HTM